# Problema ao verificar se um número é módulo de 2 em js puro

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando fazer assim:

```
if(i % 2){
   console.log(i);
 }
```

i é a variável de está vindo de um laço for.
Por que não está funcionando?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tens de comparar com `0` para verificar se o resto da divisão é zero, de resto está certo:

```
if(i % 2 == 0){ console.log(i); }
```

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    console.log(i, i % 2 == 0 ? 'é par' : 'é ímpar')
}
```

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou.